# AIR for Mobile: Fragment Equivalent

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, layout, air

Android has the ability to handle various device sizes by using the Fragment Classes.  If the activity contains a ListView and then a details activity about the item selected in the ListView, on a phone the ListView would use the available space then start the second details activity.  On a tablet, both the ListView and the details activity could be visible at the same time to prevent the entire screen from being filled with the ListView and then a second activity containing the Details about that item.

Is there an equivalent methodology if I wanted to use AIR for Android/iOS to achieve the same native outcome on various devices?  My thinking is that I would need to create a new layout manager that would be responsible for managing which Views are available depending on the screen size, but where I am stuck is trying to figure out at which proportions the views would switch from a single to a double view. Has anyone tried this approach before?  What words of wisdom can you offer?

Comment: check this new container, hope this helps http://devgirl.org/2011/12/01/flex-mobile-development-splitviewnavigator-tutorial/